# What version of MYSQL supports stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, version

Quick question - What version of MYSQL supports stored procedures?

Is it any Mysql 5.0? Or there is exact version when they implemented support like - 5.0.1.2... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/news-5-0-0.html, "basic support" for stored procedures was present in 5.0.0.

But you shouldn't use a release so old anyway, you should be using the latest release of a given major version.

Answer (score 4):

[Version 5.0.0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/news-5-0-0.html) and higher supports stored procedures. Check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-stored-procs.html) for more details. You can navigate through the FAQ for each version listed in the documentation.

If you check the [Product History in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL#Product_history), you will see that stored procedures were introduced in Version 5.0 and can be used in all the higher versions.

Answer (score 2):

Agree about "basic support" in MySQL 5.0. But I can say there might be problems with early versions (alpfa, beta). It is better to find out first release or release candidate version.